# How to change the pairing method with Bluetooth LE

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I write an application to connect a tablet with a Bluetooth LE device but when I try to connect, the "Bluetooth pairing request" dialog appears and want me to enter code on the Bluetooth device. The problem is that this device doesn't have keyboard or display. I know the pin of this device. Is there any possibility to  change a pairing method so I could enter device's pin on my tablet or form application??

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to change the pairing method from "PIN" to "OOB data". Then, you would treat the device's pin as OOB data that you enter into the tablet.

Comment: Any small hint how to do this??
Thanks in advance!